# Using Vuetify, how can I give users the option to add an item to a dropdown list?

Tags: dropdown, vuetify.js

I am creating form which has a dropdown feature that is currently pulling items (titled allDropdownTypes) from a table in my database. I've created this component using Vuetify, so it is in the following format:

```
                <v-card>
                    <v-container>
                        <v-select
                        :items="allDropdownTypes.map(a => a.value)"
                        label="Project Type"
                        >
                        </v-select>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card>
```

How can I create a way for users to add a new entry into the DB table through adding to the dropdown list?

Visually, alongside the options already given there is a + icon at the bottom of the dropdown list which will turn into a text box which the user can then submit and it will enter that option into the DB.

Comment: Have you checked Vuetify Doc about Combobox, especially the last part with customized slots. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox#advanced-custom-options